# What is the State-of-the-Art open source Voice Cloning tool right now?

Tags: nlp

I would like to clone a voice as precisely as possible. Lately, impressive models have been released that only need about 10 s of voice input (cf. https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning), but I would like to go beyond that and clone a voice even more precisely (with subsequent text-to-speech using that voice). It doesn't matter if I have to provide minutes or hours of voice inputs.

Comment: No idea about the answer but be careful: in some jurisdictions you could be sued if you use somebody's voice without their permission and make the result public.

Comment: There's [a nice summary of the present technology by Derrick Mwiti](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/a-2019-guide-to-speech-synthesis-with-deep-learning-630afcafb9dd), which doesn't really go into implementations but which may provide a starting point.

Comment: Did you find anything? I am interested in this topic and asked about it at [SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/84876/open-source-speech-to-speech-for-neural-style-transfer) with no answers so far. I found some good startups doing it, such as [play.ht](https://play.ht/voice-cloning/) and [Resemble.AI](https://www.resemble.ai/), but I would like to program and code my own vocal cloning and use it in different languages.